# Php form gives nothing

Tags: php, html

I'm quite new to php and am trying to make a simple form that mails the form-data to a specified mail address. I used [this script here](http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php) and modified it to my needs but when I try it out it just does nothing. It will go to the php page but nothing else happens and the page is empty.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form class="contact" name="contact" method="post" action="./files/php/contact_send.php">
<table id="form">
    <tr>
        <td class="data-right"><label for="naam"><b>NAAM</b></label></td>
        <td class="data-left">
            <input type="text" name="naam" size="50" style="border-style:inset"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                    <td class="data-right"><label for="mailadres"><b>E-MAILADRES</b></label></td>
        <td class="data-left">
            <input type="text" name="mailadres" size="50" style="border-style:inset"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="data-right"><label for="boodschap"><b>BOODSCHAP</b></label></td>
        <td class="data-left">
            <textarea name="boodschap" cols="39" rows="4" style="border-style:inset"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="image" src="./files/img/stuur.png" 
                onmouseover="this.src='./files/img/stuur-hover.png'"
                onmouseout="this.src='./files/img/stuur.png'"
                alt="Stuur" width="150px" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and my php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['mailadres'])) {

// CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
$email_to = "blabla@gmail.com";

$email_subject = "Contact";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "Het spijt ons maar er is iets fout gelopen bij het versturen van het formulier";
    echo "Hieronder zijn de fouten weergegeven:<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Verbeter de fouten en probeer opnieuw.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['naam']) ||
    !isset($_POST['mailadres']) ||
    !isset($_POST['boodschap'])) {
    died('Het spijt ons maar het lijkt er op dat er iets mis is gelopen met de gegevens die u heeft ingevuld.');       
}

$naam = $_POST['naam']; // required
$mailadres = $_POST['mailadres']; // required
$boodschap = $_POST['boodschap']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$mailadres)) {
    $error_message .= 'Het e-mailadres dat u heeft opgegeven is geen geldig e-mailadres.<br />';
}

$naam_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($naam_exp,$naam)) {
    $error_message .= 'De naam die u heeft opgegeven is geen geldige naam.<br />';
}
if(strlen($boodschap) < 5) {
    $error_message .= 'De opgegeven boodschap is niet lang genoeg, gelieve minstens 5 letters te gebruiken.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Formulier details:\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Naam: ".clean_string($naam)."\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: ".clean_string($mailadres)."\n";
$email_message .= "Boodschap: ".clean_string($boodschap)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$mailadres."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$mailadres."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
    Bedankt om ons te contacteren. We proberen zo spoedig mogelijk met u contact op te nemen.
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: An empty screen could mean that there was an error. Make sure php will display the error by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);` to the top of your script. Let me know if there's an error message showing.

Comment: put `<?php print_r($_POST); die(); ?>` at the very top of the page to see if your form values are submitted. Does the printed array contains the key 'mailadres'?

Comment: Ok, it's fixed. I got the error reporting fixed and it gave a few syntaxis errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error at this line:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$mailadres."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$mailadres."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' phpversion();
```

You forgot a dot in your string concatination at phpversion(). Change it to:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$mailadres."\r\n".'Reply-To: '.$mailadres."\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/'. phpversion();
```

The reason why you got an empty screen is because php is probably not displaying the error. This is a security measure. You can force php to report and display the errors by adding the next lines to the top of your script:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

You should remove these lines in a production environment because it is a security risk.

Comment: It might not be the only error, but this is a syntax error none the less and it should be corrected. php will throw a fatal error if there is a syntax error.

Comment: I have replaced the line and put in the error reporting. It still gives a blank screen, even with the error_reporting..

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if(!isset($_POST['naam']) ||
!isset($_POST['mailadres']) ||
!isset($_POST['boodschap'])) {
  died('Het spijt ons maar het lijkt er op dat er iets mis is gelopen met de gegevens die u heeft ingevuld.');       
}
```

with:

```
if ( (!isset($_POST['naam'])) ||
(!isset($_POST['mailadres'])) ||
(!isset($_POST['boodschap'])) ) {
  died('Het spijt ons maar het lijkt er op dat er iets mis is gelopen met de gegevens die u heeft ingevuld.');       
}
```

You were missing a lot of brackets for this statement.

Also, change the bottom part from:

```
?>
  Bedankt om ons te contacteren. We proberen zo spoedig mogelijk met u contact op te nemen.
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

To:

```
  echo "Bedankt om ons te contacteren. We proberen zo spoedig mogelijk met u contact op te nemen.";
}

die();
?>
```

Comment: So you go on your HTML page, fill in the form and click Submit? And it takes you to this PHP page, and there's nothing there?

Comment: Indeed, in my address bar it says .../files/php/contact_send.php but there's nothing on the page

Comment: I think jan's answer might fix your problem